# forEach function inside the object

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a question regarding this snippet of code.

```js
var names = ["John", "Jen", "Tony"];

var obj = {
 prob: function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   document.write(names[i]);
   console.log(names[i]);
  }
 },
 trim: names.forEach(function(name) {
  document.write(name)
  console.log(name)
 })
}

console.log("*********")
console.log(obj.prob());
console.log("*********")
```

If I run this code in my console I will get this:

```
John
Jen
Tony
*********
John
Jen
Tony
undefined
*********
```

That means that before my prob function that I call my trim function runs. Why is that? I didn't call it? Can I save it as a method on object and call it later when I need it?

Comment: No, your trim method does not run. But what you are trying to assign to that object property runs - `names.forEach`

Comment: You called `names.forEach` at `obj.trim`. `obj.trim` isn’t even a function, it’s the result of said `forEach` call which is `undefined`. Did you mean `trim: function(){names.forEach(function(name){`…`})}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `names.forEach` is called trying to assign the return value to `trim`. Putting it inside a function should work.

```js
var names = ["John", "Jen", "Tony"];

var obj = {
 prob: function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   document.write(names[i]);
   console.log(names[i]);
  }
 },
 trim: function () {names.forEach(function(name) {
  document.write(name)
  console.log(name)
 })}
}

console.log("*********")
console.log(obj.prob());
console.log("*********")
console.log(obj.trim());
```

Comment: Ok. So I just wrap it inside the function and it will work as expected, but isn’t any value assigned to trim without wrapping it into function? If I run obj.trim() I get an error?

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation of this behaviour:

`obj.prob` is being assigned a *function declaration* and is **not** invoked.

`obj.trim` sets an call to the function `forEach`.

***This means when you are assign to the property you are also causing the code to run*** (this happens when you instantiate the`obj` object, which explains the initial logging of names)

---

#### Suggested solution:

Wrap the invocation of `forEach` into an anonymous function declaration (just like you did with the for loop for the `prob` property):

```
var names = ["John", "Jen", "Tony"];

var obj = {
  prob: function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            document.write(names[i]);
            console.log(names[i]);
          }
        },

  // the code in this function block will only run
  // when trim is invoked
  trim: function(){
         names.forEach(function(){
           document.write(name);
           console.log(name)
          });
       }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your `each` function inside `function`

```js
var names = ["John", "Jen", "Tony"];

var obj = {
 prob: function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   document.write(names[i]);
   console.log(names[i]);
  }
 },
 trim: function(){ names.forEach(function(name) {
        alert();
  document.write(name)
  console.log(name)
 })}
}

console.log("*********")
console.log(obj.prob());
console.log("*********")
```